# matcaffe compilation error

Tags: matlab, caffe

i am trying to install caffe for matlab
while running make matcaffe i am getting the following error

some one help me how to resolve this error

but i have hdf5.h at usr/include/hdf5/serial/

```
 ./include/caffe/util/io.hpp:7:10: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
   #include "hdf5.h"
   compilation terminated.

   Makefile:454: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.o' failed
   make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Debian-derived distribution place the `hdf5` headers in a `serial` subdirectory - you may need to specify an additional include path via CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS (or their cmake equivalents, if you use cmake for the build). See related [How do I make #include “hdf5.h” find hdf5.h?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860614/how-do-i-make-include-hdf5-h-find-hdf5-h)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install single deb-package by

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
```

and then retry compilation.

Comment: i installed it by typing the above command but i am stil getting the same error